# calling mvc page from aspx project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two projects in same solution one is in mvc and other is in asp.net web form,
I want to call home page of mvc project from default page of asp.net web form project.

What is procedure for it, Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: You have 2 project in same solution but both project gets different URL when run on the browser. so give full url path of the Mvc project in ur asp.net project then u will able to access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing difficult in that , just give redirect from your default aspx page to relative path of your mvc project .
 just redirect it as like this http://www.MVCProjectname.com/
if you are on local host then use your local host path
in that replace your application port no